# Extend or modify the froala image plugin

Tags: javascript, froala

Can I extend or modify the froala image plugin?

I want to add a button for opening an image in a modal. I can't find any information about it. I want to add here: http://joxi.ru/nAyJ9Ywi1DR7rZ

Comment: As  a commercial package you should probably contact Froala through their web site or check the license you have to use it.

Comment: You probably need this https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/custom-image-button